# Pointers, Arrays and the new Operator

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
int (*ptr)[3]=new int [1][3];
```

I understand that int (*ptr)[3] creates a pointer to a 3-element integer-holding array.
I understand that new int [1][3] dynamically allocates some memory of size 1 row x 3 col x 4 bytes (32-bit machine) = 12 bytes.
I also understand that ptr [0] = &ptr [0] in this case.

1. The total memory allocated here is 3 * 12 bytes. Why?
2. Why is the 3 on the LHS dependent on the 3 on the RHS? If we use 3 on the RHS, we have to use 3 on the LHS. I cannot use 2 or 4.

Maybe it's a trivial logic, but I don't seem to find good literature on this.

Comment: 1. Where did you get this number? 2. The meaning is unclear. What kind of dependency are you talking about?

Comment: How did you know that its 3 * 12 bytes ?

Comment: @n.m. 1. I checked the memory addresses associated with each of ptr [0], ptr [1] and ptr [2], which are all 12 bytes apart. So 12 bytes * 3 such blocks. 2. Dependency: If we use 3 on the RHS, we have to use 3 on the LHS. I cannot use 2 or 4. I am not able to visualize what is being assigned to what here. (edited the question)

Comment: 1. There's no `ptr[1]`. You have only allocated an array of size 1, so you can only access `ptr[0]`. Of course there are `ptr[0][0]`, `ptr[0][1]` and `ptr[0][2]`.

Comment: I tried to check this on GCC. I get valid results when I print values for ptr [0], ptr[1], and ptr[2]. They are same as &ptr [0], &ptr[1], and &ptr[2]. Any reason why I'm getting this wrong?

Comment: By writing `ptr[1]` you do not access invalid memory. `ptr[1]` *is* an invalid address, you need to dereference it to get into trouble. Try writing someting to `ptr[1][0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the total memory allocated is *not* `3*12` bytes.  It's
`3*1*sizeof(int) + k` bytes, where `k` is unspecified (but in
most implementations, will be 0 when allocating arrays of
`int`).

Second, the two `3` must be equal because they are part of the
type.  On the left, the type is "pointer to 3 int". On the
right, you are allocating an "array of 1 array of 3 int";
because of the semantics of array new, the type of the
expression is `point to array of 3 int` (and any information
concerning whether it was `int[1][3]` or `int[2][3]` or whatever
has been  lost).  C++ uses static type checking (for the most
part), so the compiler must know all parts of the type at
compile time.

Comment: @4aRkKn1gh7 Because the standard says so:-).  The standard says so because the compiler typically has to memorize the number of elements somewhere, in order to call the correct number of destructors.  So it will be `0` if the allocated type has trivial destructors, and some value greater than `0` if it has non-trivial destructors.

Comment: Hey @JamesKanze, thanks for the response. Can you please shed more light on: "Because of the semantics of array new, the type of the expression is point to array of 3 int (and any information concerning whether it was int[1][3] or int[2][3] or whatever has been lost)." I agree that in both the cases - [1][3] and [2][3], the memory addresses occupied remain same.
Also, what is '1' in 3*1*sizeof(int) + k? If it is the first index, why wouldn't it change when the index changes?

Comment: @DMehta There's not much to clarify: the standard says that if the type allocated by `new` is "array of `T`", regardless of the `T` or the number of elements, the type of the expression is "pointer to `T`", pointing to the first element (and the number of elements is lost).  The only thing special here is that `T` is itself an array (array[3] of int).  As for the `1` in `3 * 1 * sizeof(int)`, it's the `1` in your expression `new int[1][3]`.  If you write `new int[2][3]`, then of course, it becomes `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Given the information you have provided so far, I can only answer the second part of your question:

```
Why is the 3 on the LHS dependent on the 3 on the RHS?

int (*ptr)[3] // creates a pointer to an array of 3 ints
```

that means your variable `ptr` should point to an array of array of length threes only and when you are writing  `new int [1][3]`, you are essentially creating an array of length threes with one row(2-D array) only. Similarly `new int [2][3]` would give you an array of threes with two rows.(2-D array) That's why both of the threes are dependent on each other.

Comment: They're both 2D arrays.